# Add icons to jQuery button

Tags: jquery, button

Please provide me a example for adding icons to jquery UI buttons without using javascript? i mean adding icons using themes or directly in HMTL page?

Comment: got it.

<button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-bookmark" style="float: left; margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">My Button</span>
</button>

Answer (score 2):

There's mighty descriptive information on how to do this if you just hop on over to the [official jQuery UI theming documentation](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API). Scroll down over to icons.